# UIScrollView Content Size Issue With Auto Layout

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

When I add multiple subviews to my UIScrollView, the `contentsSize` of the ScrollView does not automatically change (as the guidelines suggest they should).

If I set the `contentsSize` to 6 times the width (I'm making a 6 page scrolling view), the views are laid out properly. But I do not manually set the `contentsSize`, the scrollView won't scroll and the `contentsSize` is `(0,0)`.

The obvious answer is to just manually set the `contentSize`, but I'm nervous that I've got a more fundamental issue (or misunderstanding with Auto Layout) that will hurt me later. My code is below:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Adding a Paging ScrollView to ViewController
    let sv = UIScrollView() 
    view.addSubview(sv)
    sv.pagingEnabled = true

    let allC1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[sv]|", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["sv": sv])
    let allC2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[sv]|", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["sv": sv])
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(allC1+allC2)

    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    var subViewConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    var mySubViews:[UIView] = []

    //First SubView Add & Layout
    let firstView = UIView(withIndex: 0)
    mySubViews.append(firstView)
    sv.addSubview(firstView)
    let cWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tempView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: sv, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    let cHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tempView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: sv, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    var subViewConstraints :[NSLayoutConstraint] = [cWidth, cHeight]

    //Second through Sixth SubView Add & Layout
    for i in 1..<6 {
        let tempView = UIView()
        mySubViews.append(tempView)
        sv.addSubview(tempView)
        let cWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tempView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mySubViews[i-1], attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        let cHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tempView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mySubViews[i-1], attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        let cLeading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tempView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mySubViews[i-1], attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        subViewConstraints += [cWidth, cHeight, cLeading]
    }

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(subViewConstraints)
}
```

Comment: I am doing the basic thing I add Scroll View and than a View inside scroll view which will contain all the subviews. Define the Height Constraints to that View and problem is Solved.

What i do is Equal widths to Scrollview, Top, Bottom, MaginLeft & Trailing space with ScrollView & define explicit height of the View & problem is solved, I dont do any coding everything is handled by Storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen with manipulating UIScrollViews...it's probably best not to do that in viewDidLoad(). viewDidLoad() seems to hold true to the any x any size class in IB and doesn't account for the resizing needed to create the other size classes.

Whenever I would add anything to my UIScrollViews I would just do it all in viewDidAppear() since it seems like viewDidAppear() accounts for your screen sizes and constraints while viewDidLoad() is really just for initialization and things that should remain true for the whole time the app is available (for the most part).

Comment: thanks for the reply, but unfortunately that did not solve the issue. I tried moving the constraint code to `viewDidAppear()` and I tried it with `viewWillApear()`, and the issue persisted.